# How to insert a comment line to YAML in Python using ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have a structure like this to which I want to add comment lines using `ruamel.yaml`:

```
xyz:
  a: 1    # comment 1
  b: 2

test1:
  test2:
    test3: 3
```

Now, I want to insert comment-lines (not eol_comments) to make it look like this:

```
xyz:
  a: 1    # comment 1
  b: 2

# before test1 (top level)
test1:
  # before test2
  test2:
    # after test2
    test3: 3
```

I know, that I can add eol_comments using `ruamel.yaml`, but I didn't find a way to add whole comment lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is indeed not a function in `ruamel.yaml<=0.12.18` to insert a comment on the line before a key, but there is a function to set a comment at beginning of a structure: `.yaml_set_start_comment`. With that you could already set two of the three comments you want to add:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
xyz:
  a: 1    # comment 1
  b: 2

test1:
  test2:
    test3: 3
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
data['test1'].yaml_set_start_comment('before test2', indent=2)
data['test1']['test2'].yaml_set_start_comment('after test2', indent=4)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
xyz:
  a: 1    # comment 1
  b: 2

test1:
  # before test2
  test2:
    # after test2
    test3: 3
```

There is actually a "comment" constituting of the empty line between the value for `xyz` and `test1`, but if you append your comment to that structure and then insert a new key before `test1` things don't show up as you want. Therefore the thing to do is insert the comment explicitly before key `test1`. You can round-trip load your expected output to see what the internal `Comment` should look like:

```
yaml_str_out = """\
xyz:
  a: 1    # comment 1
  b: 2

# before test1 (top level)
test1:
  # before test2
  test2:
    # before test3
    test3: 3
"""
test = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str_out)
print(test.ca)
```

gives (wrapped this for easier viewing):

```
Comment(comment=None,
        items={'test1': [None, 
                        [CommentToken(value='# before test1 (top level)\n')], 
                        None, 
                        [CommentToken(value='# before test2\n')]]})
```

As you see `# before test2` is considered to be a comment after the key.
And doing `test['test1'].yaml_set_start_comment('xxxxx', indent=2)` will
not have any effect as the comment associated with `test1` overrules that and `# xxxxx` will **not** show up in a dump.

With that information and some background knowledge, I adapted some of the code from `yaml_set_start_comment()` (assuming the original imports and `yaml_str`):

```
def yscbak(self, key, before=None, indent=0, after=None, after_indent=None):
    """
    expects comment (before/after) to be without `#` and possible have multiple lines
    """
    from ruamel.yaml.error import Mark
    from ruamel.yaml.tokens import CommentToken

    def comment_token(s, mark):
        # handle empty lines as having no comment
        return CommentToken(('# ' if s else '') + s + '\n', mark, None)

    if after_indent is None:
        after_indent = indent + 2
    if before and before[-1] == '\n':
        before = before[:-1]  # strip final newline if there
    if after and after[-1] == '\n':
        after = after[:-1]  # strip final newline if there
    start_mark = Mark(None, None, None, indent, None, None)
    c = self.ca.items.setdefault(key, [None, [], None, None])
    if before:
        for com in before.split('\n'):
            c[1].append(comment_token(com, start_mark))
    if after:
        start_mark = Mark(None, None, None, after_indent, None, None)
        if c[3] is None:
            c[3] = []
        for com in after.split('\n'):
            c[3].append(comment_token(com, start_mark))

if not hasattr(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap, 
               'yaml_set_comment_before_after_key'):
    ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key = yscbak


data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
data.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key('test1', 'before test1 (top level)',
                                       after='before test2', after_indent=2)
data['test1']['test2'].yaml_set_start_comment('after test2', indent=4)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

and get:

```
xyz:
  a: 1    # comment 1
  b: 2

# before test1 (top level)
test1:
  # before test2
  test2:
    # after test2
    test3: 3
```

The test with `hasattr` is to make sure you don't overwrite such a function when it gets added to `ruamel.yaml`

BTW: All comments are end-of-line comments in YAML, there might just be valid YAML before some of those comments.

Comment: The method `yaml_set_comment_before_after_key()` is available in `ruamel.yaml>=0.13.0`

Comment: The method ```yaml_set_comment_before_after_key()``` works for what I need. Thanks a lot. But what I found out: When I have a multiline list like ```key: <br> - Entry1 <br> - Entry2 ```The after-comment gets inserted after the key, not after the list.

Comment: If you have a multiline list you insert it on the list/sequence element using the index in the list as key (i.e integer 0, 1, etc). See [here](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/5ca2622392115abe0657d05a6fc625946ace94c4/_test/test_comment_manipulation.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#test_comment_manipulation.py-142). Once more: just make sure `yaml_add_eol_comment` is called on the list.

Comment: Examples referenced by @Anthon appear to be viewable [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/default/tree/_test/test_comment_manipulation.py) now. Although I'm not sure if line 142 is still the right line or not.

Comment: Hm. [`test_map_set_comment_before_and_after_non_first_key_00`](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/default/tree/_test/test_comment_manipulation.py#l436) explicitly references this answer.

Comment: is there a possibility without using ruamel.yaml but just py.yaml?

Comment: @Marc I don't know what just `py.yaml`, it is not available on PyPI. AFAIK there is no other parser that can do this, that is why I developed it. At the same time it is the only parser that supports YAML 1.2 the spec for which has been out for 14 years now, so I recommend you upgrade.