# Up-to-date Ruamel comment examples

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a large YAML file that I need to add comments to programmatically for certain keys only. For example, if I see a key "foo", I always need to add a comment that says "bar".

I've tried looking at examples ([ex1](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/raml/stable/raml.pdf), [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704916/how-to-insert-a-comment-line-to-yaml-in-python-using-ruamel-yaml)) for adding comments to a YAML file using Ruamel, but none of these examples seem to work. Particularly, I can't even seem to use the `ruamel.yaml.load()` function correctly. I always get this error message: `TypeError: update() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.

I am using Ruamel 0.15.22 and Python 2.7.8. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Including some sample code which throws the TypeError

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ruamel.yaml
inp = """\
abc:
    - a # comment 1
xyz:
    a: 1 # comment 2
    b: 2
    c: 3
    d: 4
    e: 5
    f: 6 # comment 3
"""
data = ruamel.yaml.load(inp, ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader) 
data['abc'].append('b') 
data['abc'].yaml_add_eol_comment('comment 4', 1) # takes column of comment 1 
data['xyz'].yaml_add_eol_comment('comment 5', 'c') # takes column of comment 2 
data['xyz'].yaml_add_eol_comment('comment 6', 'e') # takes column of comment 3 
data['xyz'].yaml_add_eol_comment('comment 7', 'd', column=20)
print(ruamel.yaml.dump(data, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper), end='')
```

Comment: Please include the program as you have it that throws that error. And an example part of your input.

Comment: Hi Anthon, I copied the program from the ex1 link exactly (see page 9) and also have added it to the original post.

Comment: Apart from adding a newline before `data['abc'] (which gave a `SyntaxError`) that code runs fine in a virtualenv (Linux, Python 2.7.10 ruamel.yaml==0.15.22). That document however is from the wrong site, you should look at [this](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Are you on windows? macOS?

Comment: I tried the CommentedMap example from readthedocs before and also got the same TypeError. I'm on RHEL v6.6; could it be some kind of OS incompatibility? Does Ruamel have any kind of package dependencies? Everything else in Ruamel seems to work fine (regular YAML parsing/dumping).

Comment: I am developing on Linux ( Solus and Linux Mint ) running on others (CentOS 7, Debian & Ubuntu ), so I really don't believe that is the problem. Are you using a virtualenv (you should not pollute your OS' python with any installs). No package dependencies, you don't even need libyaml since some time.

Comment: I am not using a virtualenv. My company uses [Tcl modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/tcl/module.html) to dynamically load libraries such as python2.7 and ruamel, although I also don't think that would cause any significant issues. As a last resort I may try using virtualenv instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151311/discussion-between-anthon-and-ted-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that our cluster's installation of Ruamel has some issues. For now, using a Python virtualenv resolves all errors. Thanks for @Anthon for the suggestion to go with virtualenv.