# Add a comment in list element in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am dynamically adding elements in a list in a YAML file using Python and I would like to add a comment alongside each of the elements I am adding. The following are all desired formats:

```
flow_style_example:
  - [a, b, c] # first list
  - [d, e] # second list

block_style_example:
  - - a  # first list side comment
    - b
    - c
  # second list top comment
  - - d
    - e

list_of_elements_side_comment:
  - a # foo
  - b # bar

list_of_elements_top_comment:
  # comment 1
  - a
  # comment 2
  - b
```

For any of the above I have yet to figure out how to properly create the respective `CommentToken` entries, especially when it comes to marks (how to determine the line and col of what was just added?)

How can I  achieve ***any*** of the above functionalities?

Comment: @GinoMempin this is not a duplicate- the example in [How to insert a comment line to YAML in Python using ruamel.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704916/how-to-insert-a-comment-line-to-yaml-in-python-using-ruamel-yaml) refers to key value pairs (CommentedMap) entries, not entires of CommentedSeq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing in your question what you would appreciate, it would have been more useful 
to see your program, to determine what you were doing wrong.

Because you mix and match indentation styles, you cannot get the exact indentation you
want in one dump.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
CS = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq  # defaults to block style
CM = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap  # defaults to block style

def FS(x):  # flow style list
   res = CS(x)
   res.fa.set_flow_style()
   return res


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)

lst = CS()
lst.append(FS(['a', 'b', 'c']))
lst.append(FS(['d', 'e']))
lst.yaml_add_eol_comment("first list", 0, 0)
lst.yaml_add_eol_comment("second list\n\n", 1)
data = CM(flow_style_example=lst)

lst = CS()
data['block_style_example'] = lst
lst.append(CS(['a', 'b', 'c']))
lst[0].yaml_add_eol_comment("first list side comment", 0, 0)
lst.append(CS(['d', 'e']))
lst.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key(1, "second list top comment", 2)

lst = CS(['a', 'b'])
lst.yaml_add_eol_comment("foo", 0, 0)
lst.yaml_add_eol_comment("bar\n\n", 1)
data["list_of_elements_side_comment"] = lst
data.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key("list_of_elements_side_comment", "\n")

lst = CS(['a', 'b'])
lst.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key(0, "comment 1", 2)
lst.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key(1, "comment 2", 2)
data["list_of_elements_top_comment"] = lst


yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
flow_style_example:
  - [a, b, c] # first list
  - [d, e] # second list

block_style_example:
  -   - a # first list side comment
      - b
      - c
  # second list top comment
  -   - d
      - e

list_of_elements_side_comment:
  - a # foo
  - b # bar

list_of_elements_top_comment:
  # comment 1
  - a
  # comment 2
  - b
```

The comment handling for `CommentedSeq` is very similar to that of
`CommentedMap`: comments are currently stored as a dict where the
sequence index fulfills the same function as the mapping key, hence
the use of `yaml_set_comment_before_after_key` on a sequence/list.

The above uses internals of ruamel.yaml, which might change without
notice cq. with notice, but without you noticing. Therefore (be prepared
to) fix the version number of ruamel.yaml you install.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. 
> "Instead of writing in your question what you would appreciate, it would have been more useful to see your program, to determine what you were doing wrong.":

I was trying to add the elements one by one together with their comments in the list, messing with things like `ca.items`. Exactly due to the fact that I was messing with internals, which should not be needed in general, I figured it would be less confusing if I posted what I wanted to achieve. As a side note, thanks for supporting ruamel.yaml so actively.