# Changing specific variable in YAML with Python

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML Variable file for use with Ansible. 
I'm trying to build a python script to change specific variables within the YAML file.

YAML File accsw01.yml looks something like this:

```
interface_vars:
- {interface: Ethernet1/1, description: Test_interface_1, access_vlan: 10}
- {interface: Ethernet1/2, description: Test_interface_2, access_vlan: 20}
```

I use a while loop to find the right interface var in the YAML file:

```
interface = input("Enter interface: ")
yaml_file_printout = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
with open("/ansible/inventories/test/host_vars/accsw01.yml", "r") as yaml_file:
    yaml_read = yaml.load(yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    interface_count = 0
    while True:
        output_interface = yaml_read["interface_vars"][interface_count]["interface"]
        if interface != output_interface:
            interface_count += 1
        elif interface == output_interface:
            yaml_file_printout.pprint(yaml_read["interface_vars"][interface_count])
            break
```

How can I get python to change say, the access_vlan on interface Ethernet1/2 while leaving the rest of the file intact?

I've tried:

Appending the file with PyYAML but that just sticks the block of new variables on top of the YAML file..

Changing the variables with ruamel.yaml, but although it changes the variables, it removes all formatting from the YAML file and does not display the variables as a dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you cannot normally append to a YAML file, you have to read the file into a data structure, change (append, remove) the data structure, and then dump it back.

Second, you should not leave a file open unnecessarily while you go and do
other things. After doing `yaml.load()` (whether in ruamel.yaml or in
PyYAML) the data is read, so you should exit the with statement, by dedenting your code

Your program doesn't change the data read into `yaml_read`, so I tried some explicit changes:

```
import sys
import pprint
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.default_flow_style=None

interface = 'Ethernet1/1'
yaml_file_printout = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
with open("interface.yaml", "r") as yaml_file:
    data = yaml.load(yaml_file)  
interface_count = 0
while True:
    output_interface = data["interface_vars"][interface_count]["interface"]
    if interface != output_interface:
        interface_count += 1
    elif interface == output_interface:
        yaml_file_printout.pprint(data["interface_vars"][interface_count])
        break

print('------')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('------')
data['interface_vars'][1]['access_vlan'] = 30
data['interface_vars'].append(dict(interface='Ethernet1/3', description='Test_interface_3', access_vlan='5'))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
{ 'access_vlan': 10,
  'description': 'Test_interface_1',
  'interface': 'Ethernet1/1'}
------
interface_vars:
- {interface: Ethernet1/1, description: Test_interface_1, access_vlan: 10}
- {interface: Ethernet1/2, description: Test_interface_2, access_vlan: 20}
------
interface_vars:
- {interface: Ethernet1/1, description: Test_interface_1, access_vlan: 10}
- {interface: Ethernet1/2, description: Test_interface_2, access_vlan: 30}
- {interface: Ethernet1/3, description: Test_interface_3, access_vlan: '5'}
```

Instead of globally making leaf nodes flow-style (using
`yaml.default_flow_style = None`) you can also wrap the dict that is
appended in a `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()` type for finer
control over how the data is dumped (there are some details on how to
do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56471990/1307905))

Also note that the [officially recommended
extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html)
for YAML files has been `.yaml` for over 13 years now.

Comment: That's awesome thanks! I've seen a few of your replied on other threads and they've been helping me along.

Comment: If you have more questions, you know where to go. But please try to include complete, minimal, working programs in your questions, than it is easier to spot where you went wrong, had incorrect assumptions etc.